# Change step in Lua loop

Tags: lua

I work with large amount of data using Lua.
I want to move inside this circle with different steps. Very large parts of data give me losses. Small part of data gives me profit. When profit I want to move inside circle slowly with step=0.1, when losses I want to move quickly with step 1.
Help me to code this.

```
step=1
for i=1,10000,step do
 --count profit or loss
 if PROFIT then step=0.1 
 elseif LOSS then step=1
 end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

From [Lua Reference Manual 3.3.5 For Statement](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5):

> ```
> for v = e1, e2, e3 do block end
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the code:
>
> ```
>  do
>    local var, limit, step = tonumber(e1), tonumber(e2), tonumber(e3)
>    if not (var and limit and step) then error() end
>    var = var - step
>    while true do
>      var = var + step
>      if (step >= 0 and var > limit) or (step < 0 and var < limit) then
>        break
>      end
>      local v = var
>      block
>    end
>  end
> ```
>
> Note the following:
>
> **All three control expressions are evaluated only once, before the loop
>   starts**. They must all result in numbers.

So changing step inside the for loops body is not going to work. If you want changing increments in your loop use a while or repeat statement with your own counter.

Answer (score 1):

@Piglet is essentially right, but here’s another example, for clarity:

```
-- Create some fake data
-- 100 data points of profit and loss
local allMyData = {}
for i = 1, 100 do
    local data = math.random()
    if data < 0.5 then
        allMyData[i] = "loss!"
    else
        allMyData[i] = "profit!"
    end
end

local data = 1
local step = 1
while data < #allMyData do
    -- Adjust step
    if allMyData[data] == "profit!" then
        step = math.max(1, step - 1) -- Slow down!
    else
        step = step + 1 -- Speed up!
    end

    -- Step ahead
    data = data + step
end
```